# How do I force Smarty to compile my TPL template updates to PHP?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I am making updates to an old website and I do not have experience with SMARTY of TPL files and I cannot get my PHP updates to compile. Is this a cache thing or do I have to force this on the backend?

Is there a 'developer' mode I can force on to see the changes if the rendered PHP file is deleted or the respective .TPL updated?

Thanks!

(SMARTY NOOB!)

```
// Smarty file locations
$smarty->template_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/templates';
$smarty->compile_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/templates_c';
$smarty->config_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/configs';
?>
```

I have tried deleting the compile_dir and respective folders as well as applying 'no_cache' within the literal tag.  I do not have much experience with this compiling...

Comment: Cheche the `force_compile` and `caching` in `smarty.class.php`

Comment: Thanks for the response - but I set all to false and it is still compiling an old version of the tpl file. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Put `force_compile` to true, do you have a difference , Delete also your `templates_c` folder who contains the compile tpls

Comment: OMG I'm an idiot, I was editing a tpl file that wasn't being called - but that solution does work! BTW just setting to true was enough and I didn't have to clear the contents of the folder